# Automate specific steps on WordPress install

Tags: installation, automation

When I set up a WordPress project, I complete the following steps before I get to work:

1. Unpack WordPress
2. Delete pre-installed themes and copy over _s theme.
3. Set up repo via BitBucket and add to SourceTree.
4. Configure wp-config.php remembering to change the wp_ table prefix
5. Switch on debug mode
6. Set up database using a secure password
7. Install WordPress using a secure username and password. Discourage 
   search engines from indexing the site
8. Activate parent / child theme
9. Ensure permalinks are using "Post name"
10. Change admin nickname via user profile to something more secure
11. Switch off show toolbar via user profile
12. Disable comments via discussions
13. Delete default posts and pages

I understand that perhaps steps 3 and 4 will need to be done manually, but is there a way programmatically that I can automate the rest?

Comment: Have a look at Yeoman. I've written my own generator to basically handle everything you mention, based on my own starter theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a Yeoman generator. I've written one for my starter theme which you might find helpful if you write your own: https://github.com/powerbuoy/SleekWPGenerator

Comment: That's excellent, thanks. Is there any documentation to go with this or is it more of a personal project?

Comment: Yea it's very specific to my work flow, but there's plenty of other WP generators available, and I'd be surprised if _s doesn't have one already. If it doesn't do everything you want it to you can always extend it or write your own.

Comment: Here's one https://github.com/zchee/yo-underscores and there are more available at yeoman.io

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll do some more reading into this.